# Error in creating linked server

Tags: sql, security, linked-server

I have two SQL servers that both have a SQL login called "SQLAuditor" defined with the same password. I want to create a linked server where only that user can "make the jump" over to the other server. I try to do so through SSMS. On the security tab, I use the login as the local login and remote user. In the bottom of the dialog box, I indicate the for a login not defined above, a connection not be made. When I click on OK, I get the error message:

Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7416)

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please create a proper user mapping.
more on this security is listed here : [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorgepc/archive/2009/10/19/lessons-learnt-while-configuring-security-on-linked-server.aspx)